# How to implement radio buttons in Unity2D C# GUI?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a simple solution to implement radio buttons (and detect which has been clicked) in Unity2D GUI using C#.  My research has turned up many many solutions, but all for WinForms, MatLab, Rails, JAVA or some other platform. The Unity documentation shows a thing called a "ToggleGroup" but I can't seem to find any examples that show how to code it.

I'm a rookie coder, but it seems to me this should be a standard thing with tons of examples floating around.  Why can't I find a single example?

Comment: Why would you want to code it?  It is already built-in with as you mentioned toggle groups.  Not sure why there would be tons of examples showing how to use it when the documentation for it is pretty in-depth.  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ToggleGroup.html What else do you need?

Comment: I'm glad you feel that documentation is "in depth".  However it is fairly meaningless to the beginner. There is not a single example of the correct syntax, how to extract the button selected, or anything else useful that I can find.

Comment: I should also mention the toggle group has to be set up at runtime, so I don't really have access to the inspector.  If I set up a prefab, how do I access it after I instantiate? (So I can use it and then later destroy it) Again, a subject mentioned in the docs but not elaborated enough to allow a beginner to do it.

Comment: did you bother to look at the scripting API? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ToggleGroup.html  `ActiveToggles Returns the toggles in this group that are active.`  `RegisterToggle Register a toggle with the group.`  Tip, on the Unity documentation there is a Manual link and a Scripting API link, if you want to know how to do stuff in the editor, Manual is a good palce to look.  If you need scripting help click the `scripting API` link.   (Googling "toggle group unity" brings it up as the second link, first link being to the manual)

Comment: I freely admit that I don't know how to use the docs.  But when I search thru the scripting API reference, it doesn't actually show any examples.  It just sends me back to the manual page listing the methods, etc.

Comment: I have also tried searching thru Stack Overflow & other websites.  No help there as it appears every example is for some other platform or gives the solution in JavaScript, which I don't program.  I am confused especially as I need to implement this at runtime.  Whenever I do that, I can't seem to be able to "Get" the gameobject after I create it so I can't do anything with it & can't destroy it when I need to.  Please suggest more than just "look it up"! I HAVE looked it up & the manual doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say it needs to be implemented at runtime.